# No console login prompt in Xenial VM on KVM host

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, vnc

I just installed a fresh VM using Xenial beta mini.iso installation like I do for any Ubuntu based VM on my KVM based virtualisation host, but this VM doesn't show console login prompt on (KVM) VNC port. I can reach the VM perfectly fine via SSH, so there's no immediate problem. I was just wondering what's preventing Xenial from showing login prompt on KVM VNC port?

There is just one message log line in console:
/dev/vda1: clean, 60259/917504 files, 360205/3669760 blocks

but no login prompt?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Xenial tends to show the graphical console (tty7) after boot - which is unfortunately empty, except for the line quoted above.

You can 'fix' this immediately by hitting Ctrl-Alt-1 to switch to tty1, which is a text console.

To make this permanent, add a line like this to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
 GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text
```

Save and perform:

```
 update-grub
```

This makes grub tell Linux to use the "text" console after boot.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this and it seemed to be related to the kernel version. I had tried to take a short-cut by using a script I always use for provisioning headless VMs with a recent Ubuntu KVM image, and then adding I would 'apt-get' the desktop components afterwards. It nearly worked. GDM would start but Xorg couldn't find `/dev/tty1`, and there was no console output either terminal or graphical. Just a flashing cursor in top-left.

I was able to work around this. I installed the `-generic` version of the kernel, rebooted and removed the `-kvm` version. This got me further, and I then used `tasksel` to try switching it's purpose further, but I suffered a network disconnection half-way through the install so it all got messy/inconsistent. I couldn't re-connect via SSH.

I might have got further if had I kept trying, but I had already spent longer on the short-cut than expected, so I just downloaded a recent Desktop CD, mounted it into the VM and re-installed using the old-school ISO installer.